# Setting permissions for Topology Manager Roles when using Interops

Tags: publishing, templating, topology-manager, legacy-pack

I have some legacy piece of code in some old 5.3 templates which has been migrated to SDL Web 8. The offending piece of C# is as follows:

```
 String publishItemsXML = publication.GetListPublishItems(uriTarget, false, false, TDSDefinesInterop.ListColumnFilter.XMLListDefault, listRowFilter);
```

This fails with the following errors

**ERROR #1**

```
User 'DOMAIN\MTSUser' is not authorized. Current user must have at least one of the following 'ReadOnly, ReadOnlyService, Administrator' Topology Manager role(s) to perform current action.

Component: Tridion.TopologyManager.Service
Errorcode: 0
User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
```

**ERROR #2**

```
Unable to resolve the items to be (un)published.
{
  "error":{
    "code":"","message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."
  }
}

Error Code:
0x80040000 (-2147221504)

Call stack:
Microsoft.OData.Client.QueryResult.ExecuteQuery()
Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute(DataServiceContext,QueryComponents)
Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.Execute()
Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.GetEnumerator()
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1)
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1)
Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Resolving.ResolveEngine.GetPublicationIdToMappingsLookup(Session,IEnumerable`1,IList`1)
Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Resolving.ResolveEngine.GetPublishContextsPerSourcePublication(IEnumerable`1,IEnumerable`1,IEnumerable`1,Boolean)
Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Resolving.ResolveEngine.GetPublishContexts(IEnumerable`1,IEnumerable`1,IEnumerable`1,Boolean)
Tridion.ContentManager.BLFacade.Publishing.ResolveEngineFacade.GetListPublishItems(UserContext,String,String[],Boolean,Boolean,ListColumnFilter,String)
Publication.GetListPublishItems


Component: Kernel
Errorcode: 0
User: DOMAIN\MTSUser
```

**ERROR #3**

```
TemplateUtilities: Yes this caused the error:<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<tcm:Error ErrorCode="80040000" Category="18" Source="Kernel" Severity="1" xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0"><tcm:Line ErrorCode="80040000" Cause="false" MessageID="15734"><![CDATA[Unable to resolve the items to be (un)published.]]></tcm:Line><tcm:Line ErrorCode="80040000" Cause="true"><![CDATA[{
  "error":{
    "code":"","message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."
  }
}]]></tcm:Line><tcm:Line ErrorCode="80040000" Cause="false"><![CDATA[An error occurred while processing this request.]]></tcm:Line><tcm:Details><tcm:CallStack><tcm:Location>Microsoft.OData.Client.QueryResult.ExecuteQuery()</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute(DataServiceContext,QueryComponents)</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute(DataServiceContext,QueryComponents)</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.Execute()</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.GetEnumerator()</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1)</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1)</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Resolving.ResolveEngine.GetPublicationIdToMappingsLookup(Session,IEnumerable`1,IList`1)</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Resolving.ResolveEngine.GetPublishContextsPerSourcePublication(IEnumerable`1,IEnumerable`1,IEnumerable`1,Boolean)</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Resolving.ResolveEngine.GetPublishContexts(IEnumerable`1,IEnumerable`1,IEnumerable`1,Boolean)</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.BLFacade.Publishing.ResolveEngineFacade.GetListPublishItems(UserContext,String,String[],Boolean,Boolean,ListColumnFilter,String)</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>Publication.GetListPublishItems</tcm:Location></tcm:CallStack></tcm:Details></tcm:Error>


Component: Templating
Errorcode: 0
User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
```

The first of the 3 errors seems to be the key. Is there a way to make this work? Or is my legacy code (which uses interop) not going to work with the new topology manager code?

Comment: you can try to add this user to Topology Manager Administrators group which is configured in topology manager web.config or has the same name in windows groups if it is default.

Comment: Sounds like an Answer, Stanislav. :-)

Comment: Unfortunately I already tried that :( I did try enabling the legacy publishing target functionality, and it works fine there. Could it be that Topology Manager functionality simply will not work with old legacy COM Interop APIs?

Answer (score 1):

Using Topology Manager based publishing in combination with Legacy Templates should be possible. The trickiest thing is that legacy TOM API based code runs in the SDL Web COM+ Application whichs typically runs under an identity which is not authorized to access Topology Manager.

You can see that all errors are related to authorization. You may want to double-check if the DOMAIN\MTSUSER account has been correctly configured as Topology Manager (Service) User.

Sometimes a reboot does miracles... :-)

Comment: Thanks Rick, I added the MTSUser to the three default Windows Groups on the CMS Server (Topology Manager Administrators, Topology Manager Service Users and Topology Manager Users), and rebooted the machine, and still no luck :(

Comment: Weird... Is your Windows domain really called DOMAIN ?

Comment: nope, I just removed the client specific reference.